# Animating 2 fluids with different viscosities

Tags: animation, fluid-simulation

Does anyone know how to change the viscosity of a fluids simulation such as the first fluid that flows has water properties, then the fluid stops and the new fluid comes out and it has oil properties such as it flows on top of the fluid below. I know you can activate viscosity in the domain, but that will change the viscosities of both fluids, I want to control the 2 fluids separately and I cant find a way of doing it.

Cheers

Comment: Simple answer is: you cannot do this with Mantaflow in Blender. There is also no way to give different colors to multiple flow objects within a domain. Or at least not in a liquid simulation, a smoke simulation can have multicolored smoke.